# Manchester encoding

Tags: computer-networks

How clock rate is doubled in the Manchester encoding? clock cycle depends on bit interval time . In NRZ , Manchester encoding and every other Encoding the clock cycle time is same as bit interval is same.

How it is doubled clock rate?

ISRO | ISRO CS 2020 | Question 67
To send same bit sequence, NRZ encoding require
(A) Same clock frequency as Manchester encoding
(B) Half the clock frequency as Manchester encoding
(C) Twice the clock frequency as Manchester encoding
(D) A clock frequency which depend on number of zeros and ones in the bit sequence

Some one please tell why clockrate is doubled in Manchester encoding, and band width also..

NRZ, Manchester and others maintain same clock cycle time as in all bit interval time is same ??

Why?

Why?

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, your question is not very clear, but if I'm reading it correctly, you're asking why the clock rate of Manchester encoding is double that of the bit rate.

It depends on what you mean by "clock rate".

If you understand a full clock cycle as "high followed by low", or "low followed by high", then the bit rate of Manchester encoding is the same as the clock rate, in the sense that one bit is transmitted per clock cycle. Transmitting a `0` (using the IEEE 802.3 convention) is a high followed by a low, and transmitting a `1` is a low followed by a high.

However, if you understand the "high followed by a low" to be two symbols corresponding to one bit, then the *baud* rate (i.e. the number of *symbols* transmitted per second) is twice that of the *bit* rate.

Any circuitry that encodes or decodes Manchester encoding needs to be able to work at this higher frequency (propagation delay, switching speed, etc), and any accurate reconstruction of the signal requires at least one sample per symbol. I think that's why electronics engineers and signal processing people tend to think in terms of this higher frequency.

It's also why Manchester encoding is not used for modern high-speed communication; compare with 8b/10b for which the baud rate is only 25% higher than the bit rate. Still, Manchester encoding is still used. Its robustness and simplicity makes it popular for medium-speed and low-power protocols such as RFID and NFC.

Comment: But in the question they are asking NRZ has half the clock frequency of Manchester..how? It is possible

Comment: Bi-phase Encoding
The signal level is checked twice for every bit time, both initially and in the middle. Hence, the clock rate is double the data transfer rate and thus the modulation rate is also doubled..
This is the statement given .. how the clock rate doubled..??

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Manchester encoding requires (at maximum) double the number of transitions per second as NRZ, so the physical medium and any electronics need to be able to operate at double the frequency.

I don't know what you mean by "how is this possible". Are you asking how you double the frequency of a clock signal, or something like that?